# Faces Backing Bean initializing

Tags: jsf

I have a backing bean, and I'd like to load up a few lists when the bean is instantiated, so that the list may be used in a dropdown.

Is there a method that only gets called when the bean is first made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a static initializer:

```
static {
   //set up lists
}
```

Or if they aren't static lists then an initializer block:

```
{
   //set up lists
}
```

[Tutorial here.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

EDIT* Remember that these backing beans are just POJOs and work like any other Java object.  You can set up faces-config.xml like such:

```
<managed-bean-class>mymanagedBean.ConstructorName</managed-bean-class>
```

Personally I find it easier to just us an initializer block.  That's what they are for.

Comment: The problem with it is that you are missing some initialization. The other answer, suggesting @PostConstruct, will just work in more cases. Your suggestion is nice for very simple things, but it won't work if you use any dependency injection, for example. Even if you don't use DI for the moment, using @PostConstruct will let you do so in the future. Static / initializer blocks would require you to change a lot of things for DI to work later.

Answer (score 12):

Another method is to use the @PostConstruct attribute to have a method do the initializing for you once Spring/JSF has made the bean for you.

Eg:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    List<SelectItem> list = new ArrayList<SelectItem)();
    list = getService().getMenuItems();
    setMenuItems( list );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a purely declarative list of values, the faces-config.xml offers some options:

```
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>staticListOfStuff</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.ArrayList</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    <list-entries>
      <value>Value 1</value>
      <value>Value 2</value>
    </list-entries>
  </managed-bean>
```

This stuff is covered in section 5.3 The Managed Bean Facility of the [JSF 1.2 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=252).

Answer (score 0):

The JSF-y way of doing this is to bind a `PhaseListener` to the `<f:view>`, make your bean implement `PhaseListener`, then in the implementation methods populate the bean at the required stage.

Comment: This is overkill, @PostConstruct will do.

Comment: Now that @PostConstruct is an option, yes :-)